# Why my Singleton class returns two different objects?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, reference, singleton

I have written following Singleton class code,

```
class Singleton
{
private:
    Singleton(){}

public:
    static Singleton& getInstance()
    {
        static Singleton instance; //made it static so only initialized once

        return instance;
    }
};
```

Now I tried to use it,

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Singleton s = Singleton::getInstance();
    Singleton s1 = Singleton::getInstance();

    cout<<&s << "   " << &s1<<endl; //why getting different address here?

    return 0;
}
```

Both s,s1 gives different addresses.

Sample Output:

> 001AFECB   001AFEBF

I am using Visual Studio 2012. I made instance object static, so it should be initialized only once, and it should not die.

Comment: You are copying your singleton. Try `Singleton &s = ...` and `Singleton &s1 = ...`. Also, disable the copy constructor.

Comment: @Nemo Oh got it, though I am getting same instance, I am copying it to different objects?

Comment: You have to disable to the copy constructor and assignment operator for a Singelton. See: [C++ Singleton design pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/14065)

Comment: or you can start using pointers...